# Weblogic 12c - Tibco EMS - IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic12c, tibco-ems

I am having Weblogic 12c and JDK 1.7.I have enterprise application with Message Driven Bean and Foreign JMS Server(Tibco EMS - Tibco client 5.3l). When I deploy application and try to connect MDB ,I am getting below error :

```
   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp from class weblogic.deployment.jms.WrappedTransactionalSession_com_tibco_tibjms_TibjmsXAQueueSession
   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp from class weblogic.deployment.jms.WrappedTransactionalSession_com_tibco_tibjms_TibjmsXAQueueSession
   at weblogic.deployment.jms.WrappedTransactionalSession_com_tibco_tibjms_TibjmsXAQueueSession.setMessageListener(Unknown Source)
   at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.JMSConnectionPoller.disconnect(JMSConnectionPoller.java:887)
   at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDConnectionManager.timeExpired(MDConnectionManager.java:170)
   at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:304)
   at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What steps did you take to install the Tibco Weblogic foreign server configuration ?

Comment: I see a similar issue here : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3572236

Comment: Hi rjdkolb ,I only posted that in Oracle.BTW, I have tibco jar in Weblogic domain lib directory which is a version of 6.3l.And when do same with tibco 7.0l it works without any problem.Please suggest.

Comment: Ah, seems we had the same issue. Our prod Tibco EMS is 5 and I downloaded Tibco version 8, installed the driver for 8 into my lib - Weblogic 12c and it is happily consuming using my MDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Tibco 8.1.0 driver seems to solve the issue.

The Tibco EMS I am connecting to is version 5.